# Make a div that shows a series of random numbers on a loop

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to make a div which will cycle through a bunch of numbers, and upon clicking the div with the current number displayed it will be selected. The value of this div will be added to the value in another div which will have a preassigned value.

The idea is to have two divs with numbers that add up to a third number (which is also already provided). It's a game where the user has to select a number that can be added to another number to give a particular result.

[image]

I'm trying to use jQuery to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried?

Comment: something like [this](http://output.jsbin.com/wuruhufozi)? generates random number between provided range, which in this case is 2,10